# mysql select rows where sum of 2 columns > 0

Tags: mysql, select

I have a DB with a table of users where I have some user's data and 2 columns; "direct_points" and "sub_points", now these 2 columns can have a number > 0 or < 0, well I need to query the mysql db and get as results all the users where the columns ("direct_points" + "sub_points") are greater than 0.

As always thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: And what's the problem? "... WHERE `direct_points` + `sub_points` > 0"

Comment: in fact, there are no problems at all, when I've tried myself I didn't get the wanted results that's why I thought there was another way to get it, maybe I've had some other mistakes in my query... anyway thanx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from users where (direct_points+sub_points)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users
where direct_points + sub_points > 0
```